# Few TestNG classes, how to run all tests by one 'click'?

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I'm new in TestNG. In my project I have a few TestNG classes 
and I want to run methods of each classes by one 'click'.
Do anyone know how to do it? 
I use Eclipse Indigo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[This](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-5-suite-test/)** should be useful. You could create a TestNG suite, include all the tests in that and then run the Suite in a single click.

```
<suite name="My test suite">
  <test name="testing">
    <classes>
       <class name="TestNGTest1" />
       <class name="TestNGTest2" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Once you have created the above suite, you can create a TestNG launch configuration. Select the `Run / Run... (or Run / Debug...)` menu and create a new TestNG configuration:

[image]

If you do not have the TestNG plugin installed, you can do so by following the official TestNG-For-Eclipse guide **[here](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html)**.

And finally, for the One-Click-Joy, if you mark this Launch Configuration as a Favorite in the `Common` tab of the launch Configuration :

[image]

Once, you do that, this launch configuration shall be available in the Eclipse Toolbar :

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me in which XML file I need to add <suite> tag?